# GameSceneにUISegmentedControlを実装したいのですが・・・。

Tags: swift, xcode

複数のUISegmentedControlですが、条件分岐をどこで設定するのか？がわかりません。
下記コードが、今まで出来ているものです。
１つのページに３つのUISegmentedControlを設置したいので、どなたかご教授いただけませんか？

import SpriteKit

```
    class GameScene: SKScene {

        var myImage : SKSpriteNode!

        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

            //背景画像。SKSPriteNodeで画像を読み込む。
            let backGround = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"stadium414736.png")
            //画面サイズを取得
            let Label = SKLabelNode(text: "\(self.size)")
            Label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0,self.size.height/2.0)
            //背景を画面の中央に配置する
            backGround.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
            //画像のサイズを画面に合わせる
            backGround.size = self.size
            //画像を最下層に設置
            backGround.zPosition = -CGFloat.infinity
            // シーンに追加.
            self.addChild(backGround)
            // GameSceneの背景色を青色にする.
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

            // ボール画像を生成.
            myImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball04.png")
            // ボール画像の描画場所を指定.
            myImage.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
            // シーンに追加.
            self.addChild(myImage)

            // ラベル　打球種
            let dakyuushu = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
            dakyuushu.text = "打球種"
            dakyuushu.fontSize = 15
            dakyuushu.position = CGPoint(x:(size.width / 10.0) * 1 , y:(size.height / 35) * 11.1)
            dakyuushu.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.addChild(dakyuushu)
            //選択肢
            let myArray1: NSArray = ["  ゴロ  ", "  ライナー  ", "  フライ  " ]
            // SegmentedControlを作成する.
            let dakyuushu1: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: myArray1 as [AnyObject])
            dakyuushu1.center = CGPoint(x:(size.width / 10.0) * 5.8 , y:(size.height / 35) * 23.5)
            dakyuushu1.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            // イベントを追加する.
            dakyuushu1.addTarget(self, action: "segconChanged1:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            // Viewに追加する.
            self.view!.addSubview(dakyuushu1)

            // ラベル　捕球野手
            let hokyuu = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
            hokyuu.text = "捕球野手"
            hokyuu.fontSize = 15
            hokyuu.position = CGPoint(x:(size.width / 10.0) * 1 , y:(size.height / 35) * 9)
            hokyuu.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.addChild(hokyuu)
            //選択肢
            let myArray2: NSArray = ["投 ", "捕 ", "一 ", "二 ", "三 ", "遊 ", "左 ", "中 ", "右 ", "無 " ]
            // SegmentedControlを作成する.
            let hokyuu2: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: myArray2 as [AnyObject])
            hokyuu2.center = CGPoint(x:(size.width / 10.0) * 5 , y:(size.height / 35) * 27.3)
            hokyuu2.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            // イベントを追加する.
            hokyuu2.addTarget(self, action: "segconChanged2:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            // Viewに追加する.
            self.view!.addSubview(hokyuu2)

            // ラベル　結果
            let kekka = SKLabelNode()
            kekka.text = "結果"
            kekka.fontSize = 15
            kekka.position = CGPoint(x:(size.width / 10.0) * 1 , y:(size.height / 35) * 5.5)
            kekka.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.addChild(kekka)
            //選択肢
            let myArray: NSArray = ["Out ", "1BH ", "2BH ", "3BH ","HR ", "ERR ", "Fc " ]
            // SegmentedControlを作成する.
            let kekka1: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: myArray as [AnyObject])
            kekka1.center = CGPoint(x:(size.width / 10.0) * 5 , y:(size.height / 35) * 31)
            kekka1.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            // イベントを追加する.
            kekka1.addTarget(self, action: "segconChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            // Viewに追加する.
            self.view!.addSubview(kekka1)
        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch: AnyObject in touches {

                // タッチされた場所の座標を取得.
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
                //画面の中心
                let midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
                let midY = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)

                // ボール位置・軌跡のエリア条件
                let area2 = (location.x - midX) / (location.y - (midY - (midY / 5.0)))
                if location.y > midY - (midY / 5.0) {
                    if area2 >= -1  && area2 <= 1 {
                        //　打球到達エリア判定
                        let area1 = ((location.x - midX) / (location.y - midY))
                        if location.y - midY <= 0 && location.x - midX <= 0 {
                            print("left")
                        } else if location.y - midY < 0 && location.x - midX > 0 {
                            print("right")
                        } else if area1 < -0.3 {
                            print("left")
                        } else if area1 >= -0.3 && area1 <= 0.3 {
                            print("center")
                        } else if area1 > 0.3 {
                            print("right")
                        }

                        // タッチされた場所に画像を移動
                        myImage.position = location
                        // 始点を記憶するインスタンス変数
                        var position = CGPointZero
                        // 始点を記憶
                        position = self.convertPointFromView((touches.first?.locationInView(view))!)
                        // CGPathを生成
                        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
                        // 描画のペンを始点に移動
                        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, position.x, position.y)
                        // カーブを描く
                        //CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, position.x , position.y , midX, midY, midX, midY)
                        // "curve"という名前のノードがあったら消去する
                        if let theNode = self.childNodeWithName("curve") {
                            theNode.removeFromParent()
                        }
                        // pathからSKShapeNodeを生成。
                        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path)
                        // ノードに名前を付ける
                        shapeNode.name = "curve"
                        //軌跡を描画
                        self.addChild(shapeNode)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //打球種　SegmentedControlの値が変わったときに呼び出される.
        func segconChanged1(sender: UISegmentedControl){
            // CGPathを生成
            let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
            //画面の中心
            let midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
            let midY = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)
            // shapeNodeを取得
            guard let shapeNode = childNodeWithName("curve") as? SKShapeNode else {
                return
            }
            switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, position.x , position.y , midX, midY, midX, midY)
            case 1:
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, (position.x + midX) / 2.0 , position.y , midX, midY, midX, midY)
            case 2:
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, (position.x + midX) / 2.0 , (position.y + (midY / 1.5)), midX, midY, midX, midY)
            default:
                print("Error")
            }
            // 線の太さを指定
            shapeNode.lineWidth = 1.0

        }

        //結果　SegmentedControlの値が変わったときに呼び出される.
            func segconChanged(segcon: UISegmentedControl){
                // shapeNodeを取得
                guard let shapeNode = childNodeWithName("curve") as? SKShapeNode else {
                    return
                }
                switch segcon.selectedSegmentIndex {
                case 0:
                    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
                case (1...4):
                    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                case (5...6):
                    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
                default:
                    print("Error")
                }
                // 線の太さを指定
                shapeNode.lineWidth = 1.0

        }
    }
```

Comment: ソースコードを貼り付ける際は、ソースコード全体を範囲選択してエディタ上部の `{}` ボタンをクリックしていただくと、このように整形することができます。詳しくはこちら： http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/8000

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。ソースコードのまずい部分はどこになりますか？

Comment: Cocoa開発の知識はあまりないので、ちょっとわからないですね・・・。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UISegmentedControlで色を選択したときに例外が発生する原因は、mySegcon.addTarget()で指定しているsegconChanged()が呼び出せないためです。現在のSwiftでは、関数の内部関数をaddTarget()で指定することはできません。

segconChanged()を通常のメンバー関数にして、その形に合うようにSKShapeNode周りの処理を書き直せば、色の選択でSKShapeNodeの色が変わるようになります。

以下、こちらで動作を確認したソースです。
（Xcode 7.2 / iOS9で確認）

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var myImage : SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //背景画像。SKSPriteNodeで画像を読み込む。
        let backGround = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"stadium414736.png")

        //画面サイズを取得
        let Label = SKLabelNode(text: "\(self.size)")
        Label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0,self.size.height/2.0)

        //背景を画面の中央に配置する
        backGround.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        //画像のサイズを画面に合わせる
        backGround.size = self.size

        //画像を最下層に設置
        backGround.zPosition = -CGFloat.infinity

        // シーンに追加.
        self.addChild(backGround)

        // GameSceneの背景色を青色にする.
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        // ボール画像を生成.
        myImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball04.png")

        // ボール画像の描画場所を指定.
        myImage.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        // シーンに追加.
        self.addChild(myImage)

        // 表示する配列を作成する.
        let myArray: NSArray = ["  Red  ","  Blue  ","  Green  "]

        // SegmentedControlを作成する.
        let mySegcon: UISegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: myArray as [AnyObject])
//      mySegcon.center = CGPoint(x:(size.width / 5.0) * 2 , y:(size.height / 35) * 24)
        mySegcon.center = CGPoint(x:120 , y:(size.height / 35) * 24)
        mySegcon.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        // イベントを追加する.
        mySegcon.addTarget(self, action: "segconChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        // Viewに追加する.
        self.view!.addSubview(mySegcon)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            // タッチされた場所の座標を取得.
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            //画面の中心
            let midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
            let midY = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)

            // ボール位置・軌跡のエリア条件
            let area2 = (location.x - midX) / (location.y - (midY - (midY / 5.0)))
            if location.y > midY - (midY / 5.0) {
                if area2 >= -1  && area2 <= 1 {

                    // タッチされた場所に画像を移動
                    myImage.position = location

                    // 始点を記憶するインスタンス変数
                    var position = CGPointZero

                    // 始点を記憶
                    position = self.convertPointFromView((touches.first?.locationInView(view))!)

                    // CGPathを生成
                    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

                    // 描画のペンを始点に移動
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, position.x, position.y)

                    // カーブを描く
                    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, (position.x + midX) / 2.0 , (position.y + (midY / 2.5)), midX, position.y, midX, midY)

                    // "curve"という名前のノードがあったら消去する
                    if let theNode = self.childNodeWithName("curve") {
                        theNode.removeFromParent()
                    }

                    // pathからSKShapeNodeを生成。
                    let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path)

                    // ノードに名前を付ける
                    shapeNode.name = "curve"

                    // 線の色を指定
                    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()

                    self.addChild(shapeNode)

                    // ここにあったsegconChangedを外に出す
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //SegmentedControlの値が変わったときに呼び出される.
    func segconChanged(segcon: UISegmentedControl){

        // shapeNodeを取得
        guard let shapeNode = childNodeWithName("curve") as? SKShapeNode else {
            return
        }

        switch segcon.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()

        case 1:
            shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        case 2:
            shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        default:
            print("Error")
        }

        // 線の太さを指定
        shapeNode.lineWidth = 1.0

        // すでに登録済み
        // Sceneに乗せる
        //      self.addChild(shapeNode)

        // Viewに追加する.
        //self.view!.addSubview(mySegcon)

        //　打球到達エリア判定
        //

        //画面の中心
        let midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
        let midY = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)

        let area1 = ((position.x - midX) / (position.y - midY))

        if position.y - midY <= 0 && position.x - midX <= 0 {
            print("left")
        } else if position.y - midY < 0 && position.x - midX > 0 {
            print("right")
        } else if area1 < -0.3 {
            print("left")
        } else if area1 >= -0.3 && area1 <= 0.3 {
            print("center")
        } else if area1 > 0.3 {
            print("right")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございました。今後の参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: 同じ画面に、もう一つSegmentedControlを実装する場合は、どこかに条件分岐を設けないといけないとおもいますが、どこで分岐すれば良いですか？

Comment: どういう風に使うのかがわからないので答えが難しいですが、segconChanged()に当たる関数を別に用意して、そもそもの処理を分けるのが良いんじゃ無いでしょうか？

Comment: 教えていただいた内容を元に、少し変更してみましたが、やはり複数のUISegmentedControlがあると、どうも使い方がわかりません。理屈から順に教えていただけますか？

Comment: どこでつまずいているのかよくわからないのですが、うまくいかない部分を切り出して、新しく質問を立てるのが良いかと思います。

Comment: 打球種のUISegmentedControlをタップすると、
<Error>: void CGPathAddCurveToPoint(CGMutablePathRef _Nullable, const CGAffineTransform * _Nullable, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat): no current point.
というエラーが出ます。
これを解消するにはどうすれば良いですか？